# I lost my Chilean tourist card! What do I do?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, paperwork, chile

[While I was at the Thai embassy this morning](/q/24156/82), I noticed that I lost my Chile tourist card.

I have a sinking feeling that I am in for a long day.

What do I do if I've lost my Chile tourist card?  Where do I need to go, what do I need to bring, and (*sigh*) how much is it going to cost me?

Comment: Annnnnd guess what; I found my original tourist card this evening.  I knew I'd lose it if I kept it in my wallet, so I stuck it in my notebook for safekeeping.  [If I didn't have a blog to vent my travel frustrations](http://www.fiveyearsabroad.com/), I swear I would go insane :P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To request a duplicate copy of your tourist card ("Tarjeta Unica Migratoria" or sometimes "Tarjeta de Turismo"), you'll need to visit the extranjeria office.

[The office is located at Eleuterio Ramirez N° 852 in centro.](http://www.policia.cl/extranjeria/portada/mapa.htm)  Note that they are open from 8 AM until 2 PM.

Also, make sure you bring a pen with you.

To get there via Metro, take the red line to Santa Lucía and exit Avda. Bernardo O'Higgins Súr.  Walk west to San Fransisco and then go south 3 blocks to Eleuterio Ramirez.  The building will be on your right.

Once you arrive, go to the table next to the entrance and pick up 2 forms:

- Replacement tourist card (looks the same as the one you were issued when you arrived in the country).  Note that it has 3 carbon copies.
- A full-size form to request the replacement (I forget exactly what it's called, but it's the only other form on the table that mentions a tourist card).

  - [Alternatively, you can complete the form online and print it out to bring with you.](http://www.policia.cl/extranjeria/Tartur/TarTur.php)

Fill out the forms (you did remember to bring a pen, right?), and then walk straight to cubicle 10.  There is no signage; you're just supposed to know that this is where you go to replace your tourist card.

There may be an informal line in front of this cubicle; be prepared to do a little negotiation.  Also note that the PDI agent who processes your forms will probably only know Spanish.

Important:  You do **not** need to take a number*, and you do **not** need to visit the cashier ("caja")**.  **There is no fee to replace your tourist card.**

The whole process should take about 30 minutes.

<sub>* Source:  four hours of my life that I will never get back.</sub>
<sub>** Source:  another 30 minutes of my life that I also will never get back.</sub>

Comment: For future readers: while this is technically a correct answer, you actually don't need to do this as per other answers below.

Answer (score 9):

I hope someone with more experience can come along with a better answer, but since this is happening to you now I can cut/paste the official advice from the [government there](http://chile.usembassy.gov/ac_card_lost.html)

> You must replace your tourist card if it has been lost or stolen.  You are required to surrender the tourist card to International Police officers at the time you exit Chile.  If not, you will not be allowed leave the country. A duplicate tourist card must be obtained at any of the offices for Policía Internacional.  You will be required to present your passport at the time of application.
>
> In Santiago, request your tourist card at the following location and hours:
>
> Morandé 672
>
> Telephone: (2) 6809110 and (2) 6809116
>
> Hours: Monday - Friday 8:00 a.m. - 2:00 p.m.
>
> The tourist card may be replaced at the Santiago International Airport in case of an emergency.  You need to arrive at least an hour earlier than your scheduled arrival time.  We recommend, however, if possible, that the duplicate tourist card be obtained in advance at the International Police office listed above.
>
> If you will exit Chile from another departure point, you must apply for your tourist card in advance of your arrival at the point of departure.

So, you need to go there, bring your passport, I can't find anything about fees so whatever you paid for the original probably (or is that free?).

Comment: I spent all morning looking for Morandé 672.  Trust me, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Even not this Google Maps suggestion?? https://maps.google.nl/maps?q=Morand%C3%A9+672,+Santiago,+Chile&hl=en&ie=UTF8&ll=-33.436294,-70.653623&spn=0.00778,0.013937&sll=51.992171,4.494086&sspn=1.469721,3.56781&oq=Morand%C3%A9+672&t=h&hnear=Morand%C3%A9+672,+Santiago,+Regi%C3%B3n+Metropolitana,+Chile&z=17&layer=c&cbll=-33.43575,-70.65425&panoid=-YlNOBdYHAZFUvpB9LRngQ&cbp=12,235.11,,0,-0.48

Comment: I walked up and down Morandé this morning.  I assure you, there is no PDI/Extranjeria office anywhere near that address.

Comment: Sorry, I saw that text in a few places (probably all from the same source) and couldn't find anything else at all really. Hopefully the answer below puts you on the right track. Good luck with it.

Comment: The link in the post is dead, but I found this which has kinda the same content: https://cl.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/entry-exit-requirements/

Comment: For future readers: while this is technically a correct answer, you actually don't need to do this as per other answers below.

Answer (score 8):

Update 26 December 2014

I went to the PDI in Eleutiero Ramirez this morning, it's exactly where you say it is except it's three pretty long blocks from Avenida O´Higgins down San Francisco.

The routine at the PDI is now that you go to the separate entrance to the right of the main steps which is a hellish hall full of people desperate to engage with the police.  Ignore them, and go to the man at the ticket machine and ask him only for the forms to replace your 'tarjeta de entrada'.  Take them back to the main entrance where the guy on the door will now let you in, and go to the desk immediately to the left of reception where the assistant will check your entry against the computer, and stamp your form.  My total time - less than 10 minutes, as once I got back to  the main entrance I was in a queue of 3 including a nun.

NB - during Christmas dates of about 24 Dec to Jan 1, the PDI doesn´t open till 1030 am.  Fortunately, I was a bit lazy and didn´t get there till 11.

Comment: This more or less matches my experience in December 2018. The whole process took less than 5 minutes.

Comment: Also, I was worried that my weakness with Spanish would make the process difficult, but the only Spanish I needed was "Duplicado de tarjeta de tourismo" to indicate what I needed, and "Gracias" after my card was stamped.

Answer (score 8):

I lost my PDI tourist form while fishing in Patagonia. Flew out of Chile from Santiago on 2/21. At exit, gave PDI officer in booth my passport and airline boarding pass. My pp showed prior visits to Chile(3). He asked a few basic Qs, but did not even mention the missing PDI form. Wished me well and on my way. My friend, who had his PDI form, noticed it was barely glanced at and tossed into a pile of forms. A lost form does not appear to be a barrier to leaving the country.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Thanks for sharing your experience.

Answer (score 5):

According to this webpage http://www.policia.cl/extranjeria/portada.htm International Police office it's located at Eleuterio Ramirez 852, between Serrano street and San Francisco street. There are about 3 blocks from Alameda Bernardo O'Higgins street (the main street in Santiago) and it's near to Universidad de Chile.

I hope this information helps you, good luck

Comment: Thanks for the info; I stopped by a PDI office this afternoon, and they gave me the same address, so that's a promising sign.  Unfortunately, the key word there is "afternoon" — I'm gonna have to wait until tomorrow to request a new tarjeta.  That's ok though, I still get to burn through an afternoon canceling my health insurance at Masvida :P

Answer (score 5):

My cousin lost his PDI-receipt sone days before we went from San Pedro de Atacama to Bolivian altiplano. The tour companies and all the people said it would be impossible or difficult to exit chile without PDI-receipt. That turned to be false information as we went to ask for help from Carabineross in San Pedro. They told us that authorities at the border could find that PDI-thing from their database. A day later we went to the Chilean border on our way to Uyuni, Bolivia. At the border there was absolutely no problem with the lost PDI-receipt and we crossed the border to Bolivia with no trouble at all. This happened 31.12.2018

So... Try not lose your PDI-receipt. But if that happens you'll be just fine. Safe travels!

Answer (score 4):

December 2014  --- the PDI information under the US embassy Chile website - is still incorrect.

My passport was stolen on Friday, Nov 28, 2014.  The less than helpful consulate stalled me until Monday.  They issued a replacement passport at 2pm and handed me a Xerox with the correct information to replace the Chile tourist card (Eleuterio Ramirez 852 -- hours are 8a-2p.)

I used the airport location for the PDI - tourist card.  No cost, I completed one form similar to the original.  They stamped it "Duplicate" and it was all done in less than 10 minutes.   Leaving two hours later, I turned in the DUP form in the same PDI area - asked why a duplicate - I explained it was stolen.  Stamped and sent on my way.

Answer (score 4):

Lost my tourist card. Took bus from Puerto Mares to border. Was told I was in trouble. My Chilean guide was in tears with worry. At the border my passport was scanned and stamped and I went through. No one cares about the card.

Answer (score 3):

August 2022 - We also lost our tickets. Dont worry, you don't need it to leave. As long as they can see the stamp in your passport for when you entered Chile, they simply wave you through. This was Santiago Airport.

Comment: Sounds like you can just throw away the tourist card on arrival then?

Comment: I don't know all the rules and regulations, but some hotels/hostels apparently ask for it to waive the 19% tax. I threw mine away since it looked like a supermarket receipt, but later had to pay the 19% tax at one of the hostels I stayed at.