# How long does one have to keep the immigration paper given by Chilean immigration upon entering Chile?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, chile

How long does one have to keep the immigration paper  given by Chilean immigration upon entering Chile? I believe one has to present it upon departure of Chile, but does one have to keep it longer?

If that matters, assume the purpose of the entry is tourism and the visitor is a French citizen.

Example of immigration paper  given by Chilean immigration upon entering Chile:

[image]

Comment: You might want to blur out the barcode too. Most people can't scan it, but I can, and it contains all the personal information about the traveler.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks, good point definitely not a good idea to share unblurred barcodes of one's paperwork (I took the image somewhere online).

Comment: OK, if it's just an image you found on the net, then they probably don't care. Now that I look at it again, I see that they didn't even blur out their birthdate!

Comment: They may take it from you when you exit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You officially need to keep it until you leave the country. It seems however that many people lose it and it might not even be asked when you exit the country (plus the paper might have faded out which makes it even less useful). You can get a replacement before leaving the country at the Santiago airport.

Also, in some accommodations, you can avoid paying the local VAT (of 19%) if you are staying as a tourist and pay for your accommodation using US dollars and show this `Tarjeta unica migratoria` and an ID.

See [this related and useful answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24176/i-lost-my-chilean-tourist-card-what-do-i-do/40302) about getting a replacement card.

Answer (score 6):

While Vince's answer is entirely right, and you must have it until you exit the country, let me add that you must give it back to PDI at that time, so you can't actually keep it after you leave. 
Good thing or I'd have a few dozens at home by now!

Comment: Thanks, I confirm, I had to give my PDI paper to the immigration officer when leaving Chile.